# descjop template with local sqlite db?

Tags: sqlite, electron, clojurescript

I am working on a small desktop app with electron, using the [descjop](https://github.com/karad/lein_template_descjop) template for clojurescript. I don't have a lot of expirience in clojurescript, and I was wondering how I could add SQlite locally within electron and clojurescript. I would be gratefull to point me to the right direction, I am a little confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know much about Electron or descjop, so bear with me. I searched for the problem and found an answer that shows how to include sqlite. In `package.json` you need to add:

```
"scripts": {
  "postinstall": "install-app-deps"
}
```

Then you "install necessaries dependencies with":

```
npm install --save-dev electron-builder
npm install --save sqlite3
npm run postinstall
```

Then you can require SQLite in the `core` as follows:

```
(def SQLite (nodejs/require "sqlite3"))
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, but that did the trick, thank you! Just for anyone else, I had to make in the lein folder app `npm install (module name) --save` with the node modules i needed and then rebuild electron with `./node_modules/.bin/electron-rebuild -v 1.6.6 (or the latest electron version)`. Again thank you :)